# Use a form to submit a form

Tags: php, forms

I'd like some advice on passing data from form to form.  I need to do the following:

1. collect registration data from class participants
2. upon submit, authenticate and save data to the session array
3. open the payment gateway form pre-populated with data already collected
4. Upon payment confirmation, write session data to DB

It's working through step 3 (primarily in php) but it requires the user to hit a submit button in between steps 2 and 3 which I'd like to avoid.

What's the best way to post the info to the next form so that payment gateway site page opens pre-filled once step 2 is complete?

Also, my understanding that the session data will persist as long as the window is open so my plan is to have all of this happen in the same window.  Please let me know if this is flawed thinking or if there's a better way to accomplish this.

Thank you for your kind attention.

EDIT:

right now if the data is authenticated I have a function which will build the next form so:  if (!$error) {createNextForm();}

I followed that up with document.forms["paymentForm"].submit() but I think it lacks a triggering event and will just sit waiting, correct?

Comment: Submit the data to the page with the other form?

Comment: I'd probably use Javascript to check that step 2 is complete and post the form onBlur of one of the fields (ie the last field) to stage 3. Yes, you are correct that the session data will persist if you are not in a new instance of the browser. However, if you move to a new domain for the gateway the session timeout will tick down and could expire before you return to the original domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javascript you can make a form to automaticly fire the submit action.

If you have jquery, and your form is like

```
<form .... id="myform">
```

just do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myform").submit();
}
```

Without jquery:
immediately before  tag put

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('myform').submit();
</script>
```

Of course form fields have to be filled like:

```
<input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>">
```

Comment: what triggers the action?  I know just enough javascript to be dangerous and tried something similar but thought it was failing because I wasn't triggering the action.

Comment: By invoking the submit() function on a form, is the same thing of pressing the submit button. And don't be afraid about javascript, without javascript in these days you won't be able to use google, facebook, stack overflow and EVERY other website

Comment: I use it, but it's a learning experience (sometimes painful) every time!  
So I put it back in so the function builds the form: paymentForm(); followed by document.getElementById('myform').submit(); (in script) and the page comes back with the new form submit button...no action

Comment: should this work? `<form action= 'https://www.url.com/default.aspx' target='_self' id='paymentForm' name'paymentForm'><input type='hidden' name='name' value='john doe'><input type=submit id="submit" value='Pay Now' name='payment'> </form> <script type="text/javascript">document.forms.paymentForm.submit();</script>`

Comment: so I figured it out...I had to remove the submit button and then it works as I'd like...thanks for all the input!